# Difficulty in solving challenging trig equation

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

Find $\theta$ on $[0, 2\pi)$ such that

$$\cos{\theta}^{\sin{\theta}^{\cos{\theta}^{\dots}}} = 2 + 2\sec^2{\theta}\tan^2{\theta} - \sec^4{\theta} - \tan^4{\theta}$$

I'm not sure on how to tackle this problem. I've never really dealt with exponentiation of trig functions. Any help is helpful. Thank you very much

Comment: Hint:$(\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta)^2=$?

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, $\Theta=0$ is a solution. There's little hope of solving this analytically unless you can find a closed form for the left-hand side for general $\Theta$.

**Addendum:** $\Theta=\pi$ is another solution because it produces the same RHS as $\Theta=0$, and the LHS $$(-1)^{0^{(-1)^0\cdots}}$$ converges to $1$ (the value of the RHS).

Comment: I guess we may need to clarify whether we have $(\cos\theta)^{\dots}$ or $\cos(\theta^{\dots})$...

Comment: Although technically it's ambiguous, I have little doubt that the intended meaning is the former

Comment: Use the correct theta.

Comment: @Sawarnik: When I composed this answer, I used the correct $\Theta$--that is, the $\Theta$ that was used in the question. You appear to have edited the question much later and changed $\Theta$ to $\theta$ everywhere. Feel free to edit my answer as well if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

$$2 + 2\sec^2{\theta}\tan^2{\theta} - \sec^4{\theta} - \tan^4{\theta}=2+\frac{2*\sin^2\theta}{\cos^4\theta}-\frac{1}{\cos^4\theta}-\frac{\sin^4\theta}{\cos^4\theta}=\frac{2\cos^4\theta-(\sin^4\theta-2\sin^2\theta+1)}{\cos^4\theta}=\frac{2\cos^4\theta-(\sin^2\theta-1)^2}{\cos^4\theta}=\frac{2\cos^4\theta-(\cos^2\theta)^2}{\cos^4\theta}=1$$
So the whole exponent has to be 0 which is easy to tackle with(I guess you don't need help with that)

Comment: When you see something unusual in the problems don't assume it's hard,it can as well be something even easier then what you've done.Also do what you know first(right side of equation in this example) that may lead you to solution of the part you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the RHS first, we get

$$2+2\sec^2\theta\tan^2\theta-\sec^4\theta-\tan^4\theta\\=2-(\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta)^2=2-1=1$$

Now we have an easier relation to move forward with:

$$\cos\theta^{\sin\theta^{\cos\theta^{\dots}}}=1$$

But $\cos\theta=1$ exactly when $\theta=0+2k\pi$, and $\theta^x=0$ only when $\theta=0$.  For any other solution to exist, we must have some $\theta,x$ such that $\theta^x=2k\pi$, and since $\sin \theta\in[-1,1]$ we end up with $[0,\pi)^{[0,1)}\subset [0,\pi)$ and $[\pi,2\pi)^{[-1,1]}\subset [0,2\pi)$.  In the first case, $0$ is the only possible solution and in the second case, there is no possible solution.

Therefore $\theta =0$ is the only possible solution using just $\cos\theta=1$.  Follow the answer by @MPW for the additional solution $\theta=\pi$ to give $(\cos\theta)^0=1$.

Answer (score -1):

Answer is one $1$ but the answer given by the first vote is wrong because the expansion of (sin2o-1)2 is not equal to cos2o